# JavaScript scoping and hoisting: code returns 1 instead of 10 as expected

Tags: javascript

I am kind of novice in JavaScript, I really don't quite understand why the below code return `1` instead of `10`:

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
    a = 10;
    return;
    function a() {}
}
b();
alert(a);
```

The running code: http://jsfiddle.net/smMtU/

If I rem the line `function a() {}`, it returns `10` as expected. This code got from [this post](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) to explain the concept *scoping and hoisting* in JavaScript. Maybe I am missing something while reading this post?

Please anyone could point out the concept behind this code?

Comment: @j08691: Thanks for pointing you, I have flagged to close my own question too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to hoisting, your code is equivalent to

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
    var a = function() {};
    a = 10;
}
b();
alert(a);
```

Inside `b` you're not changing the external `a` but an internal one.

Answer (score 0):

This declaration creates a scope for the function `a` in the current scope before the execution.

When the `function b` is called and this line below is executed

```
a = 10;
```

there's already a scope `a` created inside the function `b`

So this becomes equivalent:

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
    a = 10;
    return;
    function a() {}
}
b();
alert(a);
```

to this:

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
    var a = function(){}; //scope created before

    a = 10; //'a' already exists in local scope, just replace it.
    return;
}
b();
alert(a); // global 'a' remains intact
```